# Not able to download all data with blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I tried to download HTML data into excel using the blob method. What now I can see is, I have an array of approx 50 items but when I check the downloaded file, it only consists of 30 items. Some items are missing. I tried to check the data in the console, it has data just data is not the excel file that i downloaded.

here is my code for the same

```
export const downloadCSV = (data, filename, image) => {
  console.log(data); //here data is correct

  var downloadLink;
  var dataType = null;

  if (image !== null && image === true) {
    dataType = null;
  } else {
    dataType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
  }

  // Create download link element
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", data], {
      type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    // Create a link to the file

    if (image) {
      downloadLink.href = data;
    } else {
      downloadLink.href = "data:" + dataType + ", " + data;
    }

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
  }
};
```

Comment: The `<a>` `download` attribute doesn't work on Safari iOS. Just an FYI, simply opening a URL that the Browser is not programmed to automatically execute should ask the Client if they want to download the file.

Comment: Please provide more info about the data. 1. How big is it? 2.What kind of data is it? Your code makes it sound like it should be a string, but if it's not encoded to base64, then your excel data will be corrupted, if it is encoded to b64, then your data URL header misses a `base64` clause and csv data will be corrupted.

Comment: @Kaiido, data is in an array format and it is very long. I won't able to upload it here. I able to download data but the problem is downloaded data is not complete.

Comment: What does`console.log(data + "").length` outputs? Are there any error message in the console?
Can't you at least make some code to produce *dummy* data that would also show that behavior? For instance  `const data = new Array(300).fill(new Array(300).fill('foobar')); downloadCSV(data, "file.csv")`